# Could you please confirm or provide a better translation for this?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to translate to my native language the content of this image:

[image]

Here's the translation I have available (not made by me, unfortunately I don't know Chinese so I have to rely on what I find online):

"Do you have to act so surprised that I've finally made it?"

I'm looking for a better translation (if there is) of the "act surprised" part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the Chinese expression is nonstandard. Some parts can be ambiguous

Comment: Haha, I am in China. Without a vpn running, I can't see your link to imgur, just a blank space. Looks like I translated the wrong sentence!

Comment: 你們倆看到我這個體育渣自己跑上來，嚇傻了吧！你们俩看到我这个体育渣自己跑上来，吓傻了吧！Are you two dumbfounded that me who is a sports challenged person is running up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

你們倆 (you two)

看到我 (seeing me)

這個體育渣 (this sport-challenged person)

自己跑上來 (ran my way up here) *he is catching up to the two people far in front of him in a run*

嚇儍了 (are stunned)

> 你們倆看到我這個體育渣自己跑上來，嚇儍了(吧?)
>
> You two seeing me- this sport-challenged person, ran my way up here. Are you astonished?

*I bet he would be left behind again when the two non-sport-challenged people start pulling away from him...*

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have to act so surprised that I've finally made it?

You have finally become successful. You tell someone. This person is surprised.

Within the context, I don't think Chinese would need the last part 'that I've finally made it'

你有必要表现得这么惊讶吗？
Do you have to act so surprised?

But if you really want the last part, try putting it first:

我最终的成功真的让你这么惊讶吗？
That I've finally made it really surprises you that much?

Edit: with the vpn on, I could see your picture.

你们俩看到我这个体育渣自己跑上来吓傻了。
You two, seeing me, a physical wreck, run up here on my own, I bet that scared you silly!